# Powershell-script: Read Contacts from excel file, and create Mailboxes for them on Microsoft Exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-3.0, exchange-server-2010

I tried things out and not with much success.
I don't want to know the whole solution for this problem, but where should I start (or maybe there already exist a solution)?
Should I better convert the excel file to CSV or XML?
Or maybe should I put some C# in it ?

Here are some more details:

1. Attributes that should be readed and then filled in the mailbox: Name, Lastname, Display Name, Alias, e-mail(genrated from name and lastname).
2. Checkbox must be unchecked: "Automatically update e-mail adresses based on e-mail adressess policy"
3. Generate e-mails from the names with addtional domain (example: Name: Dennis, Lastname: Ritchie, e-mail:Dennis.Ritchie@testdomain.com).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to add a signature to your posts - your user card is automatically displayed below them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path = "C:\Scripts\05-Script\Contacts.csv"
$Database = "xDB"
$OU = "XUnit/Test"
#$Password = (Get-Credential).Password
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssWord1" -AsPlainText -Force

Import-Csv $path | ForEach-Object   {

    $FirstName = $_."FirstName"
    $LastName = $_."LastName"
    $Alias = $_."Alias"

    $UserPrincipalName = $Alias # +xdomain.com"
    $OtherEmail = $FirstName +"."+ $LastName + "@xdomain.com"
    $DisplayName = $LastName+", "+$FirstName

    New-Mailbox -Alias $Alias `
                -Name $Alias `
                -FirstName $FirstName `
                -LastName $LastName `
                -DisplayName $DisplayName `
                -SamAccountName $Alias  `
                -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName `
                -Database $Database `
                -OrganizationalUnit $OU `
                -Password $Password `
                -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $false

}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV is certainly the easiest. You can then use

```
Import-CSV foo.csv
```

to read the file. Provided you used the appropriate column header names in the first row you can use them directly:

```
Import-CSV foo.csv | ForEach-Object { $_.Lastname; $_.'Display Name', <# etc. #> }
```

[`Enable-Mailbox`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/aa998251.aspx) seems to be the command to create Exchange mailboxes.